# ManyToMany delete delete using hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have domain `User` which may have MANY `UserResetPasswordCode`.

The code is:

**User:**

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = DomainConstant.VIEW_USER_USER_RESET_PASSWORD, joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_USER_ID)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_USER_RESET_PASSWORD_ID)})
private Set<UserResetPasswordCode> setOfResetPassword = new HashSet<>();
```

**UserResetPasswordCode:**

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "setOfResetPassword")
private Set<User> setOfResetPassword = new HashSet<>();
```

The problem is, that I want delete items in `UserResetPasswordCode`.

My code it's not working:

```
User user = userDao.findUserById(1); //really exist :-)
for (UserResetPasswordCode loop : user.getSetOfResetPassword()) {
    u.getSetOfResetPassword().remove(loop2);
}
```

Code delete value only from `name = DomainConstant.VIEW_USER_USER_RESET_PASSWORD` but value in domain `UserResetPasswordCode` still exist. Where is a problem? Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the orphanRemoval attribute which exists for the OneToMany annotation is not supported for ManyToMany. So it will be necessary to delete them on your own.

In general I avoid using cascading that mutch, because it is not that easy to use it in the correct way.